# Collection changed while enumerating; possible solution to stop and start over?

Tags: c#, exception, foreach, collections, unhandled-exception

I'm creating an airline tycoon game. In this game I'm calculating the amount of passengers on board of each different flight. To do so, I run a complex formula to compare each aspect of each flight against each other. (if the flights compete)

The filling degree gets recalculated every time the user (or AI) changes something that might influence the filling degree. Think about adding a flight, changing the price, changing the seatmap of the airliner and so on. When the game recalculates the filling degree of a set of competing flights, all previous filling degrees get deleted and the calculation starts from zero, and fills in all filling degrees one by one. (the filling degree of one flight is not used in the calculation)

This is where I assume my error happens: the game is busy comparing 7 flights, and while doing so the player adds a flight (or changes values in any flight) meaning the collection changed.

I was thinking the best solution might be to tell the game to stop its current iteration and start over again. But how would I do that? Or is there a better solution?

Sorry for the long code snippets. Many thanks in advance for helping me out!

`GetPassengers` is what gets called on a daily basis. If the filling degree values for the specific flight is empty, the calculation gets called to 
fill them in. If it's filled in, it skips the calculation and goes 
straight to the needed values.

```
public static List<FlightClassItem> GetPassengers(PoolFlight flight, PassengerRoute route)
{
        _clock.Reset();
        _clock.Start();

        var classes = new List<FlightClassItem>();

        var value = FlightFillingDegreeValues.GetElement(v => v.Departure == flight.DepartureAirport && v.Destination == flight.Destination && v.Airline == flight.Airliner.Owner.Airline);

        if (value == null)
        {
            GetOverflowTable(route, flight.DepartureAirport);

            value = FlightFillingDegreeValues.GetElement(v => v.Departure == flight.DepartureAirport && v.Destination == flight.Destination && v.Airline == flight.Airliner.Owner.Airline);
        }

        foreach (ClassTypeEnum classType in Enum.GetValues(typeof(ClassTypeEnum)))
        {
            if((int)classType <= GameTimeObject.GetInstance().GameTime.Year)
            {
                classes.Add(new FlightClassItem()
                {
                    FarePrice = route.Classes.First(c => c.Type == classType).Price,
                    Capacity = flight.Airliner.getAirlinerClassCapacity(classType),
                    Type = classType,
                    FillingDegree = value.FillingDegrees[classType],
                    Passengers = (int)value.ClassPax[classType]["Business"] + value.ClassPax[classType]["Tourist"],
                    BusinessPassengers = value.ClassPax[classType]["Business"],
                    HolidayPassengers = value.ClassPax[classType]["Tourist"]

                });
            }
        }

        _clock.Stop();
        double time = _clock.ElapsedTicks;

        return classes;
}
```

`GetOVerflowTable` is the surface of the calculation. Under this 
calculation are lots of subcalculations, with lots of foreach flight
 loops. None of these foreach loops alter any values of the flights, and certainly does not add or remove any flight or cabin class.

```
private static void GetOverflowTable(PassengerRoute route, Airport departure)
{
        Airport destination = route.Airport1 == departure ? route.Airport2 : route.Airport1;

        var season = PassengerHelpers.GetCurrentSeason(route.Airport1);
        var distance = MathHelpers.GetDistance(departure, destination);

        double touristDemand = 0;
        double businessDemand = 0;
        double cityTripDemand = 0;

        var allRoutes = Routes.GetElements(r => (r.Airport1 == route.Airport1 && r.Airport2 == route.Airport2) || (r.Airport2 == route.Airport1 && r.Airport1 == route.Airport2));

        var flights = allRoutes.SelectMany(r => r.Pool.Flights.Where(f => f.DepartureAirport == departure && (r.Type == RouteTypeEnum.Passenger || r.Type == RouteTypeEnum.Mixed_Passenger || r.Type == RouteTypeEnum.Mixed)));

        Dictionary<PoolFlight, FlightFillingDegreeValue> values = new Dictionary<PoolFlight, FlightFillingDegreeValue>();

        if (flights.Count() > 0)
        {
            var flight = flights.First();
            foreach (ClassTypeEnum classType in GetOrderedClassTypes())
            {
                double basePrice = CalculateBasePrice(route, classType);
                int supply = GetRouteSupply(route, classType);
                double sdf = GetSupplyDemandFactor(route, classType, supply);

                touristDemand += PassengerHelpers.GetHolidayPassengersDemand(departure, destination, season, null)
                    * GetAirlinerClassDistanceFactor(distance, classType, "Tourist");
                businessDemand += PassengerHelpers.GetBusinessPassengersDemand(departure, destination, null)
                    * GetAirlinerClassDistanceFactor(distance, classType, "Business");
                cityTripDemand += PassengerHelpers.GetCityPassengersDemand(departure, destination, season, null)
                    * GetAirlinerClassDistanceFactor(distance, classType, "City");

                Dictionary<EnumPassengerType, double> flightComparisonTotals = new Dictionary<EnumPassengerType, double>();

                if ((int)classType <= GameTimeObject.GetInstance().GameTime.Year)
                {
                    foreach (EnumPassengerType paxType in Enum.GetValues(typeof(EnumPassengerType)))
                    {
                        double comparisonFactorTotal = 0;
                        comparisonFactorTotal = flights.Sum(f => GetFlightComparisonFactor(f, route, classType, paxType, basePrice, sdf));

                        flightComparisonTotals.Add(paxType, comparisonFactorTotal);
                    }
                }


                var classSupplyDemandOverflowValues = GetSupplyDemandOverflowValues(flight, route, classType, basePrice, sdf, flightComparisonTotals);

                flightComparisonTotals.Clear();

                foreach (var tflight in flights)
                {

                    if (!values.ContainsKey(tflight))
                        values.Add(tflight, new FlightFillingDegreeValue()
                        {
                            Departure = tflight.DepartureAirport,
                            Destination = tflight.Destination,
                            Airline = tflight.Airliner.Owner.Airline,
                            ClassPax = new Dictionary<ClassTypeEnum, Dictionary<string, int>>(),
                            FillingDegrees = new Dictionary<ClassTypeEnum, double>()
                        });

                    if (tflight.Airliner.Classes.Any(c => c.Type == classType))
                    {
                        var clTouristDemand = classSupplyDemandOverflowValues[tflight][EnumPassengerType.Holiday_tourist];
                        var clBusinessDemand = classSupplyDemandOverflowValues[tflight][EnumPassengerType.Business];
                        var clCityTripDemand = classSupplyDemandOverflowValues[tflight][EnumPassengerType.City_trip_tourist];

                        touristDemand -= clTouristDemand;
                        businessDemand -= clBusinessDemand;
                        cityTripDemand -= clCityTripDemand;

                        if((clTouristDemand + clBusinessDemand + clCityTripDemand) > flight.Airliner.getAirlinerClassCapacity(classType))
                        {
                            if(clCityTripDemand > 0)
                            {
                                clCityTripDemand--;
                                cityTripDemand++;
                            }
                            else if (clBusinessDemand > 0)
                            {
                                clBusinessDemand--;
                                businessDemand++;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                clTouristDemand--;
                                touristDemand++;
                            }
                        }

                        values[tflight].ClassPax.Add(classType, new Dictionary<string, int>());
                        values[tflight].ClassPax[classType].Add("Tourist", clTouristDemand + clCityTripDemand);
                        values[tflight].ClassPax[classType].Add("Business", clBusinessDemand);

                        double classFillingDegree = 0;

                        if (flight.Airliner.getAirlinerClassCapacity(classType) > 0)
                        {
                            classFillingDegree = Math.Min(1,(clTouristDemand + clCityTripDemand + clBusinessDemand) / flight.Airliner.getAirlinerClassCapacity(classType));
                        }


                        values[tflight].FillingDegrees.Add(classType, classFillingDegree);

                    }
                    else
                    {

                        values[tflight].ClassPax.Add(classType, new Dictionary<string, int>());
                        values[tflight].ClassPax[classType].Add("Tourist", 0);
                        values[tflight].ClassPax[classType].Add("Business", 0);

                        double classFillingDegree = 0;

                        values[tflight].FillingDegrees.Add(classType, classFillingDegree);
                    }
                }


            }

            foreach (var value in values)
            {
                FlightFillingDegreeValues.Add(value.Value);
            }
        }
}
```

This is where we reset the filling degree of each flight on a route if for example the player adds a flight on the route. It causes the Value in the first function I shared to be 0, and thus the calculation gets called.

```
public static void ResetAirlineFlightFillingDegrees(Route route)
{
        if(route.Type == RouteTypeEnum.Passenger || route.Type == RouteTypeEnum.Mixed || route.Type == RouteTypeEnum.Mixed_Passenger)
        {
            FlightFillingDegreeValues.RemoveElements(r => r.Departure == route.Airport1 && r.Destination == route.Airport2);
            FlightFillingDegreeValues.RemoveElements(r => r.Destination == route.Airport1 && r.Departure == route.Airport2);

            var allRoutes = Routes.GetElements(r => (r.Airport1 == route.Airport1 && r.Airport2 == route.Airport2) || (r.Airport2 == route.Airport1 && r.Airport1 == route.Airport2));

            var flights = allRoutes.SelectMany(r => r.Pool.Flights.Where(f => f.Airliner.Type.TypeAirliner == AirlinerType.TypeOfAirliner.Passenger || f.Airliner.Type.TypeAirliner == AirlinerType.TypeOfAirliner.Mixed || f.Airliner.Type.TypeAirliner == AirlinerType.TypeOfAirliner.Seaplane ));


            foreach (var flight in flights)
            {
                AIModel.FlightLoadHelpers.GetPassengers(flight, route as PassengerRoute);
            }

        }

        if (route.Type == RouteTypeEnum.Cargo || route.Type == RouteTypeEnum.Mixed || route.Type == RouteTypeEnum.Mixed_Passenger)
        {
            CargoFlightFillingDegreeValues.RemoveElements(r => r.Departure == route.Airport1 && r.Destination == route.Airport2);
            CargoFlightFillingDegreeValues.RemoveElements(r => r.Destination == route.Airport1 && r.Departure == route.Airport2);

            var allRoutes = Routes.GetElements(r => (r.Airport1 == route.Airport1 && r.Airport2 == route.Airport2) || (r.Airport2 == route.Airport1 && r.Airport1 == route.Airport2));

            var flights = allRoutes.SelectMany(r => r.Pool.Flights.Where(f => f.Airliner.Type.TypeAirliner == AirlinerType.TypeOfAirliner.Cargo || f.Airliner.Type.TypeAirliner == AirlinerType.TypeOfAirliner.Mixed));


            foreach (var flight in flights)
            {
                AIModel.FlightLoadHelpers.GetCargo(flight, route as CargoRoute);
            }
        }
}
```

The crashes happen at random places in the calculation. This time it crashed in the first line in this function: (the classtypeEnum does not get changed at any place in the entire solution)

```
private static double GetVideoLevel(ClassTypeEnum type, PoolFlight flight)
{
        AirlinerClass aclass = flight.Airliner.Classes.First(c => c.Type == type);

        double basefactor = 1.3;
        double classfactor = 0;

        if (type == ClassTypeEnum.Economy_Class)
            classfactor = 0;
        if (type == ClassTypeEnum.Premium_Economy_Class)
            classfactor = -0.1;
        if (type == ClassTypeEnum.Business_Class)
            classfactor = -0.2;
        if (type == ClassTypeEnum.First_Class)
            classfactor = -0.3;

        double level = basefactor + (aclass.Video.QualityLevel.Level + aclass.Video.SizeLevel.Level + aclass.Video.Facility.BaseValue) * aclass.Video.Options.Sum(v => v.Level);

        return level + classfactor + (aclass.Video.UseAdvertisements ? -0.2 : 0);
}
```

Error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'De verzameling is gewijzigd. Mogelijk wordt de inventarisatiebewerking niet uitgevoerd.'

Translated: The collection is modified. Possibly the enumeration is not executed.

Comment: `Translated: The collection is modified. Possibly the enumeration is not executed.` That occurs when multiple threads are interacting (at least one of them must be writing) to a collection at the same time. The standard solutions are: a) Don't allow it to happen (don't interact from multiple threads). b) Use `lock` around **all usages**. c) Use a concurrent collection instead (e.g. `ConcurrentBag`).

Comment: Which **exact** line of code is throwing the exception?

Comment: @mjwills `The crashes happen at random places in the calculation.`

Comment: We need a few examples. It can't be literally crashing on **every** single line. There must be a subset of lines it is crashing on. Examples will help us to help you.

Comment: `the game is busy comparing 7 flights`  Do you have a loops running all the time in separate threads?  You need to document that.

Comment: @mjwills in the example I showed you (the last snippet), it's on the first line in the function. [AirlinerClass aclass = flight.Airliner.Classes.First(c => c.Type == type);]

Comment: @LarsTech Not all the time, only when the user makes a change to the flight or adds a flight on the route. I think the crash happens when the user adds a flight while its still busy calculating the previous change.

Comment: I believe we have not set any multithreading. But if I'm not mistaken, multithreading comes automatically when you use visuals? In our case at least you can still use the user interface while  the game is calculating things. So the user can click on 'add flights', while it's busy calculating the previous change. This button click triggers the calculation (via the third snippet)

Comment: mjwills, it seems like almost any file has using System.Threading.Taks yes. But it's always dark grey which I believe means it's unused. I'm sorry, I'm just barely a junior dev and I haven't learned yet about multithreading. I'm working along with a more experienced dev, but he's on holiday atm.

Comment: If there is **any** use of `Task.Run` (i.e. any of them run) then you have multithreading. Read my first comment. You are going to need to use one of those three options.

Comment: Task.Run was not found in the entire solution.

What do you suggest and in short what does it mean/what do I need to do to make it so.

A short summary of what the code needs to do: compare all values of the flights (eg price and capacity), this is done through the calculation. When the user or AI changes anything to the flights, the calculation needs to be redone. The problem atm is thus that the user can add flights (and trigger recalculation) while it's still calculating the previous change. The current calculation doesn't matter as the new one would override it anyway.

Comment: For clarity: if the calculation is done and all values are filled in, the calculation is not called again until there is a change to any value in the flights.

Comment: Alas, we can't help further without a [mcve] I suspect.

Comment: ` The problem atm is thus that the user can add flights (and trigger recalculation) while it's still calculating the previous change` This indicates that you must be running two threads at once. If two things are happening at the same time, then you almost certainly have multithreading.

Comment: @mjwills: I educated myself a bit on multithreading and used the lock you suggested. So far it seems to be working. Thanks! I'll ask my colleague about how we use threads when he gets back from his holiday.